# Java wrong number of arguments

Tags: java, file, exception, hashmap, illegalargumentexception

When runing this method i get wrong number of arguments exception like this :

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javafxcyberwind.Participant_MethodsIMPL.execution(Participant_MethodsIMPL.java:85)
```

The exception is in the comment line, despite the arguments entered are correct, this is my code:

```
 @Override
 public void execution(String cls, String ip, Object... par) throws InvocationTargetException, RemoteException {
        try {
            URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///" + prep)});
            Class<?> c = loader.loadClass(cls);
            Object j = c.newInstance();
            Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                ArrayList<Object> tab = new ArrayList<>();
                if (method.getReturnType() == int.class || method.getReturnType() == String.class || method.getReturnType() == boolean.class || method.getReturnType() == double.class) {
                tab.clear();
                tab.addAll(Arrays.asList(par));
                int i = 0;                    
                HashMap<Integer, File> lif = new HashMap<>();
                File file = null;
                for (Object o : tab) {
                    if (o.getClass().equals(Fichier.class)) {
                        String nomfichier = ((Fichier) o).getNom();
                        file = new File(prep + nomfichier);                            
                        lif.put(i, file);
                    }
                    i++;
                }                 
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, File> entry : lif.entrySet()) {
                    tab.remove(entry.getKey());
                    tab.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                k = method.invoke(j, tab.toArray());//line of exception
                if (file != null) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
                if (method.getReturnType().toString().equals("class java.io.File")) {
                    tab.clear();
                    tab.addAll(Arrays.asList(par));
                    int i = 0;
                    int t = -1;
                    String nomfichier = null;
                    File file = null;
                    for (Object o : tab) {
                        if (o.getClass().equals(Fichier.class)) {
                            nomfichier = ((Fichier) o).getNom();
                            file = new File(prep + nomfichier);
                            t = i;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (t != -1) {
                        tab.remove(t);
                        tab.add(t, file);
                    }
                    k = method.invoke(j, tab.toArray());
                    if (file != null) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    fff = nomfichier.replace(nomfichier, cls + "_" + nomfichier);
                    File fres = new File(prep + fff);
                    R.uploadToCloud(fff);
                    Socket s = new Socket(ip, R.getPort());
                    FileInputStream inf = new FileInputStream(fres);
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                    int n;
                    while ((n = inf.read(buf)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, n);
                    }
                    out.close();
                    inf.close();
                    s.close();
                    fres.delete();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Participant_MethodsIMPL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I can avoid the exception and make it work but as you see just for one file passed as an argument, this is the code :

```
if (method.getReturnType() == int.class || method.getReturnType() == String.class || method.getReturnType() == boolean.class || method.getReturnType() == double.class) {
                tab.clear();
                tab.addAll(Arrays.asList(par));
                int i = 0;
                int t = -1;
                File file = null;
                for (Object o : tab) {
                    if (o.getClass().equals(Fichier.class)) {//means there is an argument of type File
                        String nomfichier = ((Fichier) o).getNom();//getting the file name
                        file = new File(prep + nomfichier);//file that will replace the remote file
                        t = i;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (t != -1) {//replacing the remote file
                    tab.remove(t);
                    tab.add(t, file);
                }
                k = method.invoke(j, tab.toArray());
                if (file != null) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
```

This method is called remotely so i have to create a new file for each file passed as an argument known that the files are received in advance. 
The problem is when passing more than one file as an argument, in this case, how can i create a list of files where each file have an id that equals `i` then just browse this list ? I tried to do this with `HashMap` like on top but i keep getting the exception !

Comment: The exception says it all `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`. You are passing wrong number of arguments.

Comment: What is line 85...

Comment: @ifly6 it's tagged in the code actually, with a comment at the end of the line

Comment: Your code is blindly assuming that any method returning `int`, `String`, `boolean`, or `double` matches the parameters in `par` passed in to the `execution` method. That assumption has been proven wrong by the exception. You need to check number and type of actual parameters in `par` against the declared formal parameters of the method.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, missed it whilst skimming

Comment: @Sami I think this problem will be much easier to debug with a step-by-step debugger where you can see which method you're currently invoking and with which arguments. The exception is very explicit that there's a mismatch.

Comment: As i said the arguments are passed correctly, please read the full post.

Comment: *FYI:* Don't use string comparison to check return types. Instead of `method.getReturnType().toString().equals("int")` use `method.getReturnType() == int.class`

Comment: @Sami The arguments are not passed correctly for the method in question. They may be correct for the method(s) you *intend* to call, but the class in question may have *other* methods returning one of the 4 types you check for. Try wrapping the `invoke` call so you can see what method it's trying to call: `try { ... } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error calling " + method + ": " + e, e); }`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ --- Don't *guess* what the problem is. Debug the code so you'll know for sure. It most likely is not what you think.

Comment: I'd break on this line `k = method.invoke(j, tab.toArray());` and see what method is causing the exception.

Comment: To clarify, it's a sample method that have two parameter of type File, but the problem is not here please read the full post to understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just replacing :

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, File> entry : lif.entrySet()) {
    tab.remove(entry.getKey());
    tab.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
 }
```

By :

```
lif.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> tab.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```